# Exception while trying to execute build in ionic application

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem running the command 'ionic build android' , and I can not solve . Previously run the ionic command 'platform android add'.

```
D:\ionic\hello>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" D:\ionic\hello\hooks\a
fter_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\ionic\hello
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk-win
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gr
adle/1.2.3/gradle-1.2.3.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.585 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\ionic\hello\platforms\
android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\ionic\hello\platforms\android\build.gradle -
Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

I need to generate a package to perform a test on a android device.
my build.gradle is :

```
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
   }

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.8'
}
```

...

How can I solve ?

Comment: Hmm, not sure but make sure build tools are you to date, also make sure "extras" is installed. And of cause make sure you're connected to the internet :) Try running with --stacktrace flag and post the output.

Comment: Thanks @iCediCe, I was getting no because I was using a certificate within the jre/jdk in the root folder and that was expired, not yet , I could not download anything.

Comment: No problem, good to hear you made it work.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your old gradle-1.2.3-all.zip to new downloaded 
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip and try again.

May be your Gradle file in your C:\Users\shashi.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all